# Find all instances in a currentFrame (AS 3.0)

Tags: actionscript-3, button, flash-cs3

I have a movie with several imported videos which are instances of FLVPlayback. I want to make some Pause and Play buttons. Thus I need to know which video should I refer the stop() method to when I'm in a certain Frame. I believe it is something related to finding all existing instances in this.currentFrame and stopping the found instances. Please, Help!!!

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to loop through numChildren using getChildAt() method.